# Why can't I craft this theme?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Ok, so I've been playing FS for quite some time now and crafted a few room themes.

However, this one I'm stuck on.  As you can see, I have the materials and the caps, but somehow, I don't have time.

[image]

On the other side of the vault I have people crafting a legendary weapon for 10 days - no complaints there.

I am playing the PC version in normal (not survivor) mode.

So what's going on with this theme?

Comment: What is the total E of the dwellers in the room?

Comment: I don't recall, but the same team has created a few themes before - I generally keep the same people doing the same jobs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes seems to be some kind of glitch, just restarting the game seems to be available again.

Before restart:
[image: before restart]
After restart:
[image: after restart]

Answer (score 0):

I think it was some kind of glitch, I booted up the game today and I could craft this theme just fine!